# How do I get the background colour to change upon hover in a div dropdown

Tags: html, css, hover

I have been trying to make the colour fill the entire dropdown relative to the text you are hovering but it is not filling the whole div element, only the space around the word.

I have created a Fiddle to show the issue that I am having. I'm a beginner in CSS and HTML.

As you can see I have tried to add padding but it is not filling the div element as you hover it.

THE HTML is provided below and also within the Fiddle

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 1.0rem;
}

.sub-1 {
  display: none;
}

.sub-1 ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2rem;
  padding-right: 4rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  margin-left: -9.5rem;
  height: 27.5rem;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  background-color: white;
  list-style: none;
}

.sneakers {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.sub-1 a:link,
.sub-1 a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sub-1 a:hover {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

li:hover .sub-1 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -2rem;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px grey;
}

.search-txt {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding-top: 1.0rem;
  padding-left: 1.0rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: black;
}

.search-nav {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  list-style: none;
  gap: 2.0rem;
  margin-left: -7.0rem;
  margin-top: -0.5rem;
  caret-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">

  <body>

    <div class="navbar">

      <ul class="search-nav">
        <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#browse">Browse</a>
          <div class="sub-1">
            <ul class="">
              <li class="sneakers"><a href="#">Sneakers</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Apparel</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Electronics</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Trading Cards</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Collectibles</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">NFTs</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#help">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#account">My Account</a></li>
        <li><a class="main-nav-link sell" href="#sell">Sell</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>

</header>
```

[Fiddle](https://%20%20%20%20https://jsfiddle.net/TyDk25/7yo90zu2/4/)

Comment: `<header><body>...` is an invalid markup. Also you never close the body tag but the header tag. `<body>` is only allowed to be sued once and as direct child to the `<html>`-tag. everywhere else it is invalid. Please use a [Markup-Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) the enxt time first! Also post a working [repro] the next time. Postign a fiddle is acceptable as add-on but should never replace a working code snippet here for these reason: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/ PS: Instead of using `<div class=navbar">` you should use the semantic `<nav>`-tag

Answer (score -1):

if i understand correctly the wrapper div with the sub-1 class is unnecessary. If you remove that div and add that class to the ul below it

```
      <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#browse">Browse</a>
        <ul class="sub-1">
          <li class="sneakers"><a href="#">Sneakers</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Apparel</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Electronics</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Trading Cards</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Collectibles</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">NFTs</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Then in your css add a background-color

```
 li:hover > .sub-1{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: -2rem;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px grey;
 background: red;
}
```

I hope this helps, cheers!